# jQuery script stops working with 1.7 - any ideas why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I was running this script to highlight the active page in bold. I had to run jQuery 1.7 for Fancybox and now the scripts broken.

Any ideas and even better, solutions - would be much appreciated!! :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var parts = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var page = parts[parts.length-1];
$('.statusBar a[href*=' + page + ']').addClass('activeBold');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: What is broken about it?

Comment: Any error message occours in the error console of Firefox, Safari or Chrome browser?

Comment: What is the specific error here? Is there an error message? Is there an unwanted side-effect? Does the effect you want not appear?

Comment: What does that pathname look like?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the issue, but you should quote your attribute selectors.

```
$('.statusBar a[href*="' + page + '"]')
```